# Stop $timeout update in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 controllers, both use the same update method to get data:

```
angular.module('project')
  .controller('mainController', function($http, $scope, $timeout, $sce) {
      updateData($http, $scope, $timeout, $sce, false);
  })

  .controller('settingsController', function($http, $scope, $timeout, $sce) {

      updateData($http, $scope, $timeout, $sce, true);          
  })
```

my `updateData` looks like this:

```
function updateData($http, $scope, $timeout, $sce, settings) {
    $timeout(function() {
        if (settings) {

            getSettings($http, $scope);
        }
        else {
            getDataA($http, $scope);
            getDataB($http, $scope);
        }
        updateData($http, $scope, $timeout, $sce, settings);
    }, 1000);
}
```

Now when refreshing the main page (using `mainController`) I always get 'null' messages, because the process did not complete all method calls, and when switching to another site (using `settingsController`) it takes ages to load it because all requests from the previous one have to be completed first. How do I directly "kill" all pending updates when refreshing/switching site?

Comment: Its incorrect implementation..passing dependency as parameter to method isn't correct.. rather method should be there inside a service. so that we can ask for data from them..

Answer (score 3):

1. This implementation is wrong. I don't think it's a good idea to pass a dependency to an open function and use them. This can create hard-to-detect bugs.
2. Your `updateData` function is a resource killer. It recurs every second without a limitation or control.

There is a design issue in your code. You should reconsider designing it in a standard and effective way.

The answer to your question is that `$timeout` returns a promise. You can use the $timeout.cancel method to cancel the timeout.

```
var timeoutPromise = $timeout(foo(), 1000);

$timeour.cancel(timoeoutPromise);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should make a service instead of the function. then you need to inject the service into the controllers.

```
project.service('updateService', function(){
    ...some logic here...
});
```

then inject:

```
angular.module('project')
 .controller('mainController', function($http, $scope, $timeout, $sce, updateService) {
        ...use "updateService" methods here...
})
```

and when you write a controller, a small tip, write it like this:

```
angular.module('project')
 .controller('someController', ['$scope', function($scope){

}];
```

this is important for when you want to make minified version of your code.

Comment: so I put 2 methods (updateData and updateSettings) in a service, call one in each controller, which then automatically stops being executed when the controller changes/refreshes?

Comment: @JustSomeDude , yes and this is the right thing to do. it is safer and easy to debug.    i hope you liked my answer. if i can help in any other way please ask.

Comment: I just checked services and I think I'm still confused, it seems to me like a service is actually just a function, so do I create two services now? One for each controller (e.g. updateSettingsService and updateDataService)?

Comment: think of a service as a placeholder for a logic (or atlist this is what i am doing), that several controller need to inherit. you can make two service and inject both it is totally fine.   if you liked my answer please accept it.

Comment: in my getDataA, getDataB methods I set the data directly in $scope, which is why I passed it thorugh all methods, also I call updateDate in updateData itself so it will be executed every second... would you mind showing me how the service would look like in my case, I cant figure it out